# Why do my C# unit tests for exceptions fail if I use try/catch?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm using C# with nUnit to unit test my project and I'm trying to write some unit tests that ensure a certain Exception is called but my tests keep failing.  After a lot of testing to work out the issue, I managed to identify the cause of it and created a small code example that shows my issuew below.

My unit test code:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestExceptionIsRaised()
    {
        var ex = Assert.Throws<UnauthorizedAccessException>(() => TestExceptionMethod());
        StringAssert.Contains("Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation", ex.Message);
    }
```

My method with no error checking:

```
public void TestExceptionMethod()
{
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
}
```

Now if I run that unit test with the above method... it throws the exception, nUnit detects it and the test passes.  However, this code is a problem because it has no error handling and will crash if I release it like this.

So to solve that problem, I add some error handling into my method like this:

```
   public void TestExceptionMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            // Do something about the error
        }
    }
```

But now when I run the unit test it fails with this error:

> Expected: System.UnauthorizedAccessException 
>   But was:  null

So rather than having to choose between a unit test or proper error handling, I tried to re-throw the error like this:

```
public void TestExceptionMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                // Do something about the error
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Finally, everything now works.  The unit test passes every time.  And my method can still catch the error and do something about it.

However from what I've heard it isn't good practice to keep re-throwing errors like this???  So I'm just wondering is my solution "correct"?  Or is there a better way of unit testing for an exception without having to remove the try/catch blocks from the original method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However from what I've heard it isn't good practice to keep
>   re-throwing errors like this???

There is nothing wrong with re-throwing exceptions. It's actually a best practice to re-throw the exception after your application runs some logging code **without recovering your application state**.

> Or is there a better way of unit testing for an exception without
>   having to remove the try/catch blocks from the original method?

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. But if you expect an exception thrown from your method, there must be an exception for your test to pass no matter it's thrown directly or re-thrown. If you `try/catch` like this:

```
public void TestExceptionMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            // Do something about the error
        }
    }
```

The test will fail for sure because the exception is **swallowed**. The test cannot detect there was an exception inside the method.

Comment: Oh I think I'm starting to see what you mean.  The only thing I still don't understand is that before I started writing unit tests for exceptions, I never used the Throw keyword.  I just used to use Try { something } Catch (SomeException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) }; and that worked perfectly to catch exceptions even if I don't throw them in the catch block.  So I'm not 100% sure why that worked but now I have to re-throw them in the catch block for the unit test to work?

Comment: @Calcolat: when you use `Assert.Throws`, the exception `must` be thrown. Did you use `Assert.Throws` in your previous unit test?

Comment: Ahh I get it now.  No I haven't used Assert.Throws before.  I've only done normal unit tests that don't test for any exceptions.  I see what you mean now.  If I'm not unit testing the exceptions, I don't have to re-throw the exception.  But if I'm using Assert.Throws, the exception must be thrown hence I have to re-throw it.  Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Translating your test into English you are saying:

> "I expect the method TestExceptionMethod to throw a
>   UnauthorizedAccessException. The message of which will contain a
>   string with more details."

By not throwing the exception this test will **never pass**. If you don't want the exception to be thrown you need to change your test. If you do want the exception to be thrown, what you're doing is correct.

**Is this correct?**

It depends. If what you're doing is an exceptional issue, then throw an exception. Let the program crash. Fix the bug.

On the other hand if this is something that is to be expected such as bad user input, boundary conditions, handle it if you can. If you cannot recover from the problem then throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling done poorly can make debugging more difficult especially when the exception is swallowed, or when a new exception instance is created and thrown losing the stack trace of the original exception. Sometimes the latter is desirable when you need a more abstract exception higher up the call stack, in which case you can add the original exception as an inner exception to keep access to the stack trace.